# python-setuptools : How to overwrite files of other package?

Tags: python, setuptools, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

The query I have is a simple one :)
But I am struggling a bit with the answer

Problem Statement :-

I have a python package which builds and installs using python-setuptools.
I need to include 3 python files into the same package and create an RPM which on installation will overwrite 3 files from another package(installed in /usr/lib/python-xx/site-packages...)

And I don't know how to achieve that ?
I just need some way to hard code the 3 file names and replace them at specific location, which might change depending upon the python-xx version.

Also define that other python package as my dependency for this RPM to install.

Comment: Have you considered forking the package you need to overwrite, modifying the fork and making *that fork* a dependency of your project? The approach you're considering seems likely to be very fragile (what if the user installs it in a `virtualenv`, for example?)

Comment: Yes, I considered the fork option. But that package is coming from a community which is changing rapidly. We don't want the overhead of maintaining our own fork. The package will be installed in our controlled environment and will not be available outside our appliance. So I thought that going this way would be the most easiest one.

Comment: Well how were you planning to merge any changes they make that affect the files you're overwriting? You're going to have to do some maintenance, and a fork is the logical way to do it.

Comment: Well there is bit more to it than I stated. The community repo is forked and maintained for us by another team. All we get is an RPM. Getting my code changes merged with that other team is a long long process. Though I agree that it would be the best way to go forward in the long run. But today to test my package, I just need this functionality of overwriting the rpm installed files with my packaged files. This is just a make shift arrangement till we get those processes in place.